# Binomial Series of form $(1-x^2) ^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

A question asks to use binomial series to find Maclaurin series for following:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{{(4 + x^2)}^{1/2}}$$

Considering the x inside the radical is squared, the question is not of form: $${{(1 + x)}^{k}}$$

In general, how does one use binomial series when the x inside the expression is squared? I've attempted splitting denominator into
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{{(2-x)}^{1/2}}\frac{1}{{(2+x)}^{1/2}}$$

Getting power series of one and dividing end result by other denominator, but doesn't come out to the textbook's answer which is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)^n(1)(3)(5)...(2n-1)x^{2n}}}{2^{3n}n!}\right)$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. More simply, it’s $\dfrac12(1+y)^{-1/2}$, where $y=\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2$

Comment: your denominator split/factorisation is wrong

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks, and yes, that explains where the 2^3n came from.

Answer (score 2):

For $f(x) = \frac{1}{{(4 + x^2)}^{1/2}}=\left(4+ x^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is possible to use [Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) for real power $-\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\left(4+ x^2 \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}4^{-\frac{1}{2}-k}x^{2k}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}$

Comment: i'd also take out $\sqrt 4 $ out